# SPARQL query split by case

Tags: sparql

Is it possible to use a built-in SPARQL function to split a string by case?

For example take the following test AllDrugs

Is possible to use a function that would return "All Drugs"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you just need to replace the pattern **([a-z])([A-Z])** with **$1 $2** (where **$1** is the lower case letter and **$2** is the upper case letter).  Here's an example:

```sql
select * where {
  values ?string { "AllDrugs" "FourScoreAndSevenYearsAgo" }

  bind(replace(?string, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2") as ?splitString)
}
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| string                      | splitString                      |
==================================================================
| "AllDrugs"                  | "All Drugs"                      |
| "FourScoreAndSevenYearsAgo" | "Four Score And Seven Years Ago" |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```